# C# call method (params object[][]) with object[] and object[][] as parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, parameters

I have a method

```
public void method(params object[][] arg)
```

But where I call the method, I have and object[] and object[][]:

```
object[] var1 = new object[5];
object[][] var2 = new object[8][5];
method(var1, var2); (I´d like this to be method(var1, var2[0], var2[1], var2[2],...)
```

But inside method, arg has length 2:

```
arg[0] = var1
arg[1] = var2
```

But I want arg as an array of length 9:

```
arg[0] = var1
arg[1] = var2[0];
arg[2] = var2[1];
...
```

How can I call the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
object[][] args = new[] { var1 }.Concat(var2).ToArray();
method(args);
```

The "normal" parameter array handling of C# doesn't do any flattening: you *either* call it with a single argument which is already the right type, *or* you call it with a sequence of arguments of the element type. You can't mix and match.

Answer (score 2):

In general, for methods that accept a `params` array I also provide an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public void MyMethod(params string[] args)
{
    MyMethod((IEnumerable<string>)args);
}

public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<string> args)
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you can also easily provide an enumerable as the parameter. For example:

```
string[] var1 = new string[5];
string[][] var2 = new string[8][5];

// Jon Skeet's suggestion without ToArray():
var sequence = new[] { var1 }.Concat(var2);
MyMethod(sequence);
```

---

If you really want to use the syntax you propose, you can do that since in your example you use `object[]`. An array of objects is also an object, therefore you can do the flattening *inside* your method:

```
public void MyMethod(params object[] args)
{
    object[] flattened = arg
        // For each element that is not in an array, put it in an array.
        .Select(a => a is object[] ? (object[])a : new object[] { a })
        // Select each element from each array.
        .SelectMany(a => a)
        // Make the resulting sequence into an array.
        .ToArray();
    // ...
}

MyMethod(var1, var2);
```